# Rholang : What's the difference between @process and *name

Tags: rholang

Run the following code snippets on https://rchain.cloud/ and I have the following result.

**Code Snippet I**:

```
new test in {
  for(@x <- test){
     @"stdout"!(x)
  } |
  test!(1)
}
```

Output is `1`

**Code Snippet II**:

```
new test in {
  for(x <- test){
     @"stdout"!(*x)
  } |
  test!(1)
}
```

Output is `1`

**Code Snippet III**:

```
new test in {
  for(@x <- test){
     @"stdout"!(x+1)
  } |
  test!(1)
}
```

Output is `2`

**Code Snippet IV**:

```
new test in {
  for(x <- test){
     @"stdout"!(*x+1)
  } |
  test!(1)
}
```

It ends with an error

> Error: parallel or non expression found where expression expected.

**Code Snippet V**:

```
new test in {
  for(x <- test){
     @"stdout"!((*x)+1)
  } |
  test!(1)
}
```

Now if I try to modify the code a bit, it ends with another error.

> Unimplemented expression:
>   Expr(ETupleBody(ETuple(Vector(Par(Vector(),Vector(),Vector(Eval(Some(Channel(ChanVar(Var(BoundVar(0))))))),Vector(),Vector(),Vector(),Vector(),Vector(),Vector(),BitSet(0),false)),BitSet(0),false)))

**Question**: 
Snippet I is equivalent to II.
Then why do snippet IV and V raise errors but III does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run snippets IV and V on rnode 0.5.3 they output 2 as you probably expected.

I confirm that they do not behave that way on rchain.cloud though. Perhaps they are running an older node version?

Comment: Yes, they are running an old version.  It's something that an rchain member set up; it's not an official rchain website.